# List/Retrieve HDFS partitions as Map(String,List(String)) from spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I wanted to know if there is some way to leverage the metadata information already present in the hdfs folder structure in spark. For example, I am using the following code to write data to hdfs,

```scala
val columns = Seq("country","state")
dataframe1.write.partitionBy(columns:_*).mode("overwrite").
save(path)
```

This generates similar looking directory structure,

```
path/country=xyz/state=1
path/country=xyz/state=2
path/country=xyz/state=3
path/country=abc/state=4
```

What i want to know is using spark, is there a way to infer all the partitions and sub partitions as a `Map(String,List(String))` (without loading the entire file and using group by?), where the key is the partition and the value is a list of all the sub partitions within this partition.

The output of the above example would be similar to following

```
Map(xyz->List(1,2,3),abc->(4))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your hdfs file structure is like this...

```
$tree path
path
├── country=abc
│   └── state=4
└── country=xyz
    ├── state=1
    ├── state=2
    ├── state=3
    ├── state=4
    ├── state=5
    └── state=6
```

you need to use this for getting full paths as string..

```
val lb = new ListBuffer[String]
  def getAllFiles(path:String, sc: SparkContext):Unit = {
  val conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
    val fs = FileSystem.get(conf)
    val files: RemoteIterator[LocatedFileStatus] = fs.listLocatedStatus(new Path(path))
    while(files.hasNext) {
      var filepath = files.next.getPath.toString
      //println(filepath)
      lb += (filepath)
      getAllFiles(filepath, sc)
    }
    println(lb)
  }
```

once you get listbuffer with all files full path including subfolders... you need to write the logic to fill 
in to map. that I am leaving it to you. TIY..

Note : ListBuffer has group by which returns map may be you can use it

in my case I experimented like this...

```
  println( lb.groupBy(_.toString.replaceAll("file:/Users/xxxxxx/path/country=", "")substring(0, 3) ))
```

I got the result like

```
Map(abc -> ListBuffer(file:/Users/xxxxxx/path/country=abc, file:/Users/xxxxxx/path/country=abc/state=4), xyz -> ListBuffer(file:/Users/xxxxxx/path/country=xyz, file:/Users/xxxxxx/path/country=xyz/state=1, file:/Users/xxxxxx/path/country=xyz/state=6, file:/Users/xxxxxx/path/country=xyz/state=3, file:/Users/xxxxxx/path/country=xyz/state=4, file:/Users/xxxxxx/path/country=xyz/state=5, file:/Users/xxxxxx/path/country=xyz/state=2))
```

may be you can use this idea to further refine to your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was just wondering if there isnt a way to do this natively in spark, for example 

`spark.read.load("path").select("country","state").groupBy("country").toMap`

Comment: Afaik no. For hive spark.sql(show partitions rable ) is there but you need to make a map with that. Hdfs partitions you need to read from Hadoop configuration as above